# WPF MVVM Samples with Database

Tags: wpf, database, mvvm, connection-string

What examples exist of Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) Model View ViewModel (MVVM) that include sample database connections?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **BookLibrary** (WPF MVVM) sample application of the **[WPF Application Framework (WAF)](http://waf.codeplex.com)** uses the Entity Framework in combination with a SQL CE database.

Answer (score 4):

you could have a look at those:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPF_MVVM_DB_Access.aspx

or just this:

http://www.google.com/search?q=mvvm+database

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend Building Enterprise Applications with Windows Presentation Foundation and the Model View ViewModel Pattern publish by Microsoft.

http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0790145309686.do#tab_04_0

you can find the source code here

http://examples.oreilly.com/9780735650923-files/